# Python 2.7 web scraping: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape from this site, but  am unable to fix this error:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I am trying to use unicodedata method to remove \xa0 (appears when there are empty p tags) from parsed string.

```
pages = ["http://sg.startupjobs.asia/sg/job/search?w=jobs&q=data+scientist+OR+data+analyst+OR+business+analyst+OR+business+intelligence&l=Anywhere&t=any&job_page=" + str(i) for i in range(1, 12)]

job_links = []

for p in pages:

    r  = requests.get(p)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").text
    clean_soup = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", soup)

    container = clean_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'yw0'})
    for text in container:
        job_names = text.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'JobRole'})
        for name in job_names: 
            for link in name.find_all('a'):
                job_link = link.get('href')
                job_links.append("http://sg.startupjobs.asia" + str(job_link))
```

Answer (score 0):

the type of clean_soup is unicode not BeautifulSoup.

```
clean_soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(clean_soup)
clean_soup_2.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'yw0'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Change

```
r  = requests.get(p)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").text
clean_soup = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", soup)

container = clean_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'yw0'})
```

to

```
r = requests.get(p)
clean_text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', r.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(clean_text, 'lxml')

container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'yw0'})
```